# Выбрать элемент из div

Tags: javascript

Есть элементы, к примеру 3

```
<div class="page"">
  <div class="itemHolder">
    <div class="item" id="1"">
      <img src="картинка">
      <div class="price">10</div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="itemHolder">
    <div class="item" id="2"">
      <img src="картинка">
      <div class="price">20</div>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="itemHolder">
    <div class="item" id="3"">
      <img src="картинка">
      <div class="price">30</div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Как определить на какой itemHolder мы щелкнули и вывести price?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
event.target.closest(".itemHolder").querySelector(".price").textContent
```

и не забыть по полифилл для https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/closest.

Comment: Как например вывести price в консоль?